# How to hibernate Windows on Power Loss and Wake When Power is Restored?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, sleep, hibernate, wake-up

I'm running a Windows 8 tablet in my car as my stereo and have it powered to the ignition (so it only charges on ACC).

I'm using EventGhost for automation processes and I'd like to be able to have it force the tablet to hibernate when the ignition is turned off and then wake when power is restored.

Since EventGhost can use command line arguments to execute various functions it should be able to do this. However, I can't figure out the correct commands to carry this out. Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't used EventGhost before but I would think that hibernating when the power is turned of would be possible. But the reverse would be unlikely. While the computer is off EventGhost can not run or take any actions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's the case. There is an Android program called Autosleeper. Each time you switch off your cars’ engine your android goes automatically to sleep within seconds. Then, when you turn the car’s engine on again and power supply starts, your android wakes up on its own and continues exactly where you left it. I tried using this with Bluestacks (an android emulator) but didn't have any luck. If anyone knows of a Windows program that does this automatically I'd love to know.

Comment: I just had a quick look into AutoSleeper. It seems that it is not turning off the device, just the screen. Android devices are typically designed to enter low power states with the screen off, but the device is still on. With Windows hibernate however, the system's current state is saved to disk and the device cuts off all power.

Comment: Hmm. Well, if there's no way to issue commands to wake from hibernation then commands for sleep or hybrid sleep would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use eventsleeper to wake from either sleep, or hibernate, but you can set your tablet to hibernate very shortly after the ignition is turned off.

In windows 8 power options, choose to change the settings of your power plan, then choose advanced settings.

Under the sleep catagory, expand Hibernate, or sleep (whichever you want) and set it to 1 minute when it's on battery. This will tell the tablet to sleep, or hibernate one minute after it loses power from ACC.

Do not set both sleep, AND hibernation to 1 minute. If you use hibernation, it should always have a higher wait time, than sleep.

Comment: Yeah, I already have Windows set up this way. The Windows power settings are okay for putting the tablet to sleep but I'd prefer something a little more elegant. If I can't find a way to auto-power the tablet back on, is there a way to manually change Windows to go to sleep in say 10 seconds rather than 1 minute?